# Automatically Restarting Website after IIS AppPool recyle

Tags: iis, web, scheduled-tasks, application-pool, recycle

I'm using a website which interacts with SQL Server Agent in order to schedule the automatic processing and emailing of reports.  I recently noticed that when the AppPool recyles, that i'm not getting reports afterwards - until someone logs into the website again.  It's possible for the website not to get hit for hours/days, during which all the scheduled tasks are lost.

I'd like to set up a windows task to either run periodically or trigger off the AppPool recycle event.  But I'm not sure what the task should be.  I had one suggestion to set up a Windows task to exercise a .js script that would hit the website, but this only works with Windows Authentication (which isn't being used):

```
var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/website/default.aspx", false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Looking for some suggestions on how to "wake up" a website after an IIS AppPool recycle.

Thanks.
ab.

Comment: To address the Basic Authentication challenge, I added the credentials as:  xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/website/default.aspx", false, "user", "password);

Comment: Rather than create a Windows task that runs periodically, I tied the action to an event by using the Windows Event Viewer and attaching the task to the IIS AppPool Recycle event.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run [gnu wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) from a scheduled task:

```
wget -O - http://mysite.com/default.aspx
```

Comment: The scenario in question is running on a customer system and I'm somewhat limited in what I can add on their system.

Comment: @Andrew - so no console access?

Answer (score 0):

I ran across [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/688/using-the-iis-application-warm-up-module/) today which seems like it might help you out. It's the IIS Warm-up module. Depends on whether you can convince the your customer to install it, although it is an official IIS module, so hopefully it's no problem.